# Select.PDF <img> Not Appearing in Rendered PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, azure-webjobs, azure-blob-storage, selectpdf

I am using select.pdf to output a PDF file. My process starts by grabbing the text of an HTML file in my visual studio project using this:

```
string strHTML = string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines("Template.html", Encoding.UTF8));
```

Once I have the strHTML set to the text from the HTML template, I run a few replaces to replace variables I have in the template, like this:

```
strHTML = strHTML.Replace("PARAM_A", "My Replaced Value");
```

Once all of that is done, I render the PDF using:

```
 PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(strHTML);
```

My problem is this - In the Template.html file I have an HTML img that has a src property set to an image in a Publicly Available Azure BLOB container, like this:

```
<img style="float:left; height:125px; width:125px" src="FULL PATH TO PNG IN AZURE BLOB CONTAINER" />
```

While developing and debugging on my local machine, everything works great and the PDF includes the image referenced. The project is an Azure Web Job and when I deploy it, the PDF gets generated as expected but the PDF does not include the image.

I read that the Select.pdf ConvertHtmlString method takes two parameters, my strHTML text and also a baseUrl string property, but I'm not sure what to put here in my situation. I am dynamically generating all of the HTML and then trying to output the PDF.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Daniel

Comment: Press `F12`, Please check whether the img resource has been loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jason. In my function, I am building a string variable that is the complete HTML document, but never rendering it to a browser. I am using the slelectPdf method PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(strHTML) to output that string to a PDF, and then I am saving the PDF to a BLOB container. There is never an opportunity to use the developer tools to see if the img is rendered,

Answer (score 1):

As your description, I can see that you convert complete HTML document to a string, and then convert it to pdf.

Use the command include two parameters:

```
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString, baseUrl);
```

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/selectpdf/selectpdf-free-html-to-pdf-converter) works perfectly.

And this is the decompile code may help you to refer:

```
public PdfDocument ConvertHtmlString(string htmlString, string baseUrl)
    {
      int num1;
      PdfDocument pdfDocument;
      short num2;
      switch (0)
      {
        case 0:
label_2:
          pdfDocument = (PdfDocument) null;
          num2 = (short) 4;
          num1 = (int) (IntPtr) num2;
          goto default;
        default:
          while (true)
          {
            switch (num1)
            {
              case 0:
                if (!GlobalProperties.RenderWithRestrictedEngine)
                {
                  pdfDocument = PdfDocument.ᜀ(this.ᜁ((string) null, htmlString, baseUrl, baseUrl, false));
                  num2 = (short) 3;
                  num1 = (int) (IntPtr) num2;
                  continue;
                }
                num2 = (short) 5;
                num1 = (int) (IntPtr) num2;
                continue;
              case 1:
              case 3:
                goto label_13;
              case 2:
                num2 = (short) 0;
                num1 = (int) (IntPtr) num2;
                continue;
              case 4:
label_3:
                num2 = (short) 1;
                if (num2 == (short) 0)
                  ;
                if (this.Options.RenderingEngine != RenderingEngine.WebKitRestricted)
                {
                  num2 = (short) 2;
                  num1 = (int) (IntPtr) num2;
                  continue;
                }
                break;
              case 5:
                num2 = (short) 21784;
                int num3 = (int) num2;
                num2 = (short) 21784;
                int num4 = (int) num2;
                switch (num3 == num4 ? 1 : 0)
                {
                  case 0:
                  case 2:
                    goto label_3;
                  default:
                    num2 = (short) 0;
                    if (num2 == (short) 0)
                      break;
                    break;
                }
                break;
              default:
                goto label_2;
            }
            pdfDocument = PdfDocument.ᜀ(this.ᜀ((string) null, htmlString, baseUrl, baseUrl, false));
            num2 = (short) 0;
            num2 = (short) 1;
            num1 = (int) (IntPtr) num2;
          }
label_13:
          return pdfDocument;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for the hep, Doris. I have read the article but in my situation, what is the value of baseUrl?

Comment: This parameter allows the converter to resolve relative urls. Basically, `baseUrl + relative image/css url = full absolute url`. Reference:https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/M_SelectPdf_HtmlToPdf_ConvertHtmlString_1.htm

Comment: Actually you can set the `baseUrl` to `https://{webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/` @DanielG